# Create array from ForEach loop

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I want to create an new array from JSON data instead of hard coded data below

```
let data: [DataPoint] = [
    .init(value: 20, label: "1"),
    .init(value: 30, label: "2")
]
            
BarChart(dataPoints: data))
```

Using `ForEach` loop to retrieve each data from json, but i don't want generate multiple bar charts for each data

```
let newArraydata: [DataPoint]

ForEach(json.data){ chart in
    let data: [DataPoint] = [
       .init(value: Double(chart.value), label: chart.label)
    ]

    // BarChart(dataPoints: data))
}

BarChart(dataPoints: newArraydata))
```

Expected array output

```
[
    .init(value: 20, label: "1"),
    .init(value: 30, label: "2")
]
```

How to use `ForEach` loop to create an new array in order to populate the chart data

Comment: What is json.data and instead of `ForEach(json.data) {...` did you mean to do `json.data.forEach {...`?

Answer (score 1):

Try out this playground:

```
import UIKit

let jsonStr = """
[
    {
        "value": 20,
        "label": "1"
    },
    {
        "value": 30,
        "label": "2"
    }
]
"""

struct DataPoint: Codable {
    let value: Int
    let label: String
}

let jsonData = jsonStr.data(using:.utf8)!

do {
    let points = try JSONDecoder().decode([DataPoint].self, from: jsonData)
    print(points)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This shows you how to properly parse your JSON to a `DataPoint` array, I guess you will easily be able to turn this into a `BarChart`. It is really no problem to conform to Codable, this is the Swift way to quickly parse JSON (with very decent error messages btw.).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do:

`BarChart(dataPoints: json.data))`